# Links in colorbox iframe opening in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

This is a tricky one. I have a link on my page that opens a Colorbox iframe to an external website. The external website contains links to another page. When the user clicks those links, I need them to load up in the same iframe.

The problem is, the link on that external site is set to open a new window with target="_blank". Therefore, instead of this page loading within the same colorbox iframe like I need it to, it opens a totally new window.

Is there any way to bypass it so that these links within the iframe do not open a new window, and instead load that window within the same colorbox iframe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**_blank** will always open a new window, you could try **_TOP** instead, it should work something like this;

```
<a onclick="parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();" href="NEW SITE" target="_top">
open in parent window with animation
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the document that is being displayed in the iframe?  If so you could handle things a little differently so that you only opened new windows if the document isn't being displayed in an iframe.  But if the document you are iframing isn't under your control then I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: It is an external site that I don't control :/